how to push value into a ref array
as shown below in the code, in the constructor i create a ref array. i want to push this.#recentlyHoveredGeomProps.value into the reactive array object which is this.#recentlyHoveredGeometriesProps.
but for the code posted below, when the listen() is called, i receive the following results despite i am sure that this.#recentlyHoveredGeomProps.value has values:
recentlyHoveredGeometriesProps":[]

to solve this i tried the following:
const arr = new Array()
arr.push(this.#recentlyHoveredGeomProps)
this.#recentlyHoveredGeometriesProps.value = arr;

then, listen() return values.
what is wrong in the following approach please:
this.#recentlyHoveredGeometriesProps.value.push(this.#recentlyHoveredGeomProps.value);

code
constructor() {
        this.#recentlyHoveredGeometriesProps = ref([]);
}
...
...
this.#recentlyHoveredGeometriesProps.value.push(this.#recentlyHoveredGeomProps.value);

listen() {
    return this.#recentlyHoveredGeometriesProps;
}


i guess the full code is needed, please create a working example on https://play.vuejs.org/

"what is wrong in the following approach" - what did make you think there's something wrong? Is there an error? IIRC your previous questions showed that there may be problems when you use # private fields with reactive class proxy because it doesn't have access to them
